# How can I add a symbol to a callout label in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, labeling

I want to achieve something like this Barnett Bridge callout with a National Park Symbol underneath it.

I realize these maps are done using Illustrator, but I'm trying to stay in the realm of QGIS as much as possible.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Using rule-based labeling you can create two sets of labels with the same rule.

One to print the text, and one using a "symbol" font print the symbol you want.

You will need to adjust the placement of the two labels so they work together, and you will need to install the required font on all machines that will display the labels.

Comment: Thanks! I will give this a try!

Answer (score 1):

the QGIS print composer is able to handle this manually, using the ‘add picture’ button. This example shows a label with an icon that comes bundled with QGIS, but you can use any picture:

[image: adding an icon to a label with QGIS print composer add picture]